# Cannot Find name h1 - HTML Tag on .tsx file Next.js Project

Tags: typescript, next.js13

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYXjC.png)

I get some highlight syntaxis on my .tsx file, as usual, i made a next.js project but using typescript.

I have tried to change tsconfig jsx to react-jsx, and make sure the file extension was .tsx, but vscode still give me highlight like error syntaxis on my html tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, problem was solved by restarting Visual Studio Code totally, after install Typescript snippet extension on Visual Studio Code. Thanks.